# mysql select from table using the distinct count of specific column

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a table with two columns, dept_id and loc_id as following:

```
+----------+--------+
| dept_id  | loc_id |
+----------+--------+
|    1     |    1   |
|    2     |    1   |
|    2     |    2   |
|    3     |    1   |
|    3     |    2   |
|    3     |    3   |
|    3     |    4   |
|    3     |    5   |
+----------+--------+
```

I want to select the first two 'dept_ids' dynamically without using "IN" as I don't know the first two 'dept_ids', and then select the next two 'dept_ids' .. and so on, so it should retrieve this if I select the first two:

```
+----------+--------+
| dept_id  | loc_id |
+----------+--------+
|    1     |    1   |
|    2     |    1   |
|    2     |    2   |
+----------+--------+
```

Is that possible?

I am using a MySQL database, with PHP as programing language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL has no concept of "first" row, unless another column specifies the ordering.  If you have only one table, you can effectively do what you want using:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select dept_id
      from table t
      group by dept_id
      order by dept_id
      limit 0, 2
     ) td
     on t.dept_id = td.dept_id;
```

You would just change the `0` to `2` then `4`, and so on.

More commonly, I would expect you to have a `Departments` table.  If so:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select dept_id
      from Departments d
      order by dept_id
      limit 0, 2
     ) td
     on t.dept_id = td.dept_id;
```

In either case, you want an index on `dept_id` for performance.